# Add many routes using Google Maps Directions Service Over Query Limit

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have an application that requires having many (sometimes over 50) dynamic routes added to the google map.  Using the DirectionsService, I am able to add right around 10 routes or so before the requests start to fail with the status of "Over Query Limit".  I was wondering if anyone has encountered this situation and has found a way to deal with it.  It seems that even if I pause between requests, I am still failing for anything over the first 10.  Not sure if there is a request limit for a single map instance?

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score -2):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#Limits), you can only get up to 2 requests per second. If your code do that slower than 2 per second, that should be fine. 
I used the `setInterval(function(){....` to test it and yup, if you do it slow enough it seems to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/bd1qdLv3/

Comment: Thanks for the help, but wondering if you can show an example that will allow for more than 10 routes to appear on the map at the same time?  That I am still unable to do.

Comment: That you, sir.  That seems to do the trick.  I will upvote once I get the reputation points.  I appreciate your help.