# OVER_QUERY_LIMIT being hit with Geocoder

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-geocoder

I have an application where the address of a location needs to be shown from a GPS coordinate. The code is using the Map and Geocoder API.

When calling for the display of 12 map points and address locations at the same time I get the OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error for 7 of the addresses (it displays all map points and 5 addresses).

The Google account is setup for billing and required APIs have been enabled.

Have been researching delaying the display of points, but ultimately unsuccessful.

This is what some of the code looks like:

position = new google.maps.LatLng({{ asset.last_location.0 }}, {{ asset.last_location.1 }});

```js
position = new google.maps.LatLng({{ asset.last_location.0 }}, {{ asset.last_location.1 }});
      
/* determine the physical location */
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': position }, function (results, status) {

  // display error if one occurs in the log
  if (status !== google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    console.log(status);
  }

  // display the address
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    console.log(results);
    address = (results[0].formatted_address);
    console.log(address);
    $('.location_{{ asset.id }}').html(address);
  } else {
    $('.location_{{ asset.id }}').html('Error determining address location');
  }
});

/* store the marker */
var marker_{{ asset.id }} = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: position,
  map  : map,
  title : "{{ asset.asset_reference }} - {{ asset.asset_name }}",
  icon : {
    path   : google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
    fillColor  : '#00F',
    fillOpacity  : 0.6,
    strokeColor  : '#00A',
    strokeOpacity : 0.9,
    strokeWeight : 1,
    scale   : 4
  }
});
```

Comment: 1) [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 2) What's your question?

Comment: Are you aware about per session limit in Maps JavaScript API: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42876576/5140781?

Comment: Thanks for sending that link @xomena that solved my problem :)